# How to use the object of one class into another class' definition or declaration

Tags: c++, class, object

Here is a piece of code that embodies the problem:

```
class Apples {
    Apples() {
        color = 5;
    }
    int color;
};
Apples jonathan;
class Fruit {
    Fruit() {
        type = jonathan.color;
    }
    int type;
};
```

Error given is: 'jonathan' undeclared (first use this function).

Comment: This code should give more errors than that

Answer (score 0):

The way you posted it won't cause that error. If they're on different files, you just have to make sure that the necessary portions are on header files and include (with #include) the necessary headers.

Comment: Indeed, the code is not real, nor claimed I it is. Apart from some trivial errors it contains, it will work, although I stated it won't. I misinterpreted my real problem. The fact is that, as user1610015 suggested, each class is in a different header and that the definition of each uses the objects of the other, hence the error. I am sorry for misinterpreting.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will cause compile time error (such as constructor being private). So this is not the real code.

However, using global variables is considered a bad practice, and instead, you must use member variables, and pass the reference along on a needly basis.

note, your `Apple()` constructor is private. So is `Fruit()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

in c++
Apples jonathan; is declared inside main

```
int main()
{
    Apples jonathan;
}
```

now you are calling the method of the object (jonathan.color) inside a class which is not possible

Comment: `Apples::color` is not a method but a data member; using it is possible if it were declared `public`.